# How do I enable OAuth2 for only certain classes in my Spring Boot Security OAuth2 app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I followed this guide to add OAuth2

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/#_securing_a_rest_service

But now it's requiring authentication for every single page!

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/login 
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

I only want to use OAuth2 on the API in one specific class. I tried reading the reference for Spring Boot

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security

But it wasn't helpful at all! It gave 0 examples.

> To customize it you normally use external properties and beans of type WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (e.g. to add form-based login). 
>   All of the above can be switched on and off or modified using external properties (security.*). To override the access rules without changing any other auto-configured features add a @Bean of type WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) and configure it to meet your needs.

*How* do you customize it?! *Which* properties?! *How* do you configure to meet your needs?!

I tried setting `application.properties`

```
security.basic.enabled = false
security.ignored = /login
```

But it still requires OAuth2 authentication. I want to only enable OAuth2 for the class `IShortUrlApiInteface` and disable it for all other `@Controllers`.

Comment: Show your resource server configuration.

Comment: Here is the `@EnableResourceServer` class. https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/7289fcb52d882ec4b084a994d75ebc3d

Comment: Youdidn't configure the security, therefor by default all URLs are secured.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that when I asked the question, so how do I enable OAuth2 only for certain classes?

Comment: *Here is the @EnableResourceServer class.* That is your authorization server class. You need a second class for your resource server.

Comment: [The guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/#_securing_a_rest_service) says explicitly "OAuth is very flexible. You could, for example, deploy an authorization server that’s shared by many REST APIs. In this case, our OAuth implementation lives adjacent to our bookmarks REST API. They are one and the same. This is why we’ve used both \@EnableResourceServer and \@EnableAuthorizationServer in the same configuration class."!

Comment: i didn't say that you need two different applications, I said, that you need two configurations in the same application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a *new* class, extend `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, and override method `configure(HttpSecurity)`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    String [] ignoredPaths = new String[]{
            "/robots.txt", "/error", "/login", "/doLogut", "/home", "/pageNotFound", 
            "/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/img/**", ...
    };

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(ignoredPaths).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic();   
    }
```

Comment: OK but you can see from the guide there is no `configure(HttpsSecurity)` method. Nevertheless, I tried to add your method and the IDE gave an error: `The method configure(HttpSecurity) of type OAuth2Configuration must override or implement a supertype method`. This cannot be the answer. Still, I created `@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, added your method, and now _nothing_ is protected! `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer bad-token"  localhost:8080/isTagAvailable`
`HTTP/1.1 200`.

Comment: OK I got it to work and edited your answer. Unbelievable how simple it was. I was trying thousands of variations of `configure(HttpSecurity)` through `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` but it would muck everything up and give extremely strange errors and make it impossible to debug. Just the mere existence of that class breaks the app and paths!

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you need to set the permission for login URI.
If you are in micro service architecture, you need create resource configuration in every project/service.

- security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri defines authorization service URI
- clientId defines ur actual client id
- In oauth For every resource server  need to create unique resource-id 
  Below is the example for resource server.

  @Configuration
      @EnableResourceServer
      public class ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
          @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri}")
          private String userInfoUri;

  ```
  @Value("${client-id}")
  private String clientId;

  @Override
  public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
      resources.resourceId("ig-user");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/user/activate/**").permitAll()//
              .antMatchers("/api/v1/user/access/check/**").permitAll()//
              .antMatchers("/api/v1/profile/exists/**").permitAll()//
              .antMatchers("/api/v1/user/sign-up/**").permitAll()//
              .antMatchers("/download/**").permitAll()//
              .anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public UserInfoTokenServices tokenService() {
      final UserInfoTokenServices tokenService = new UserInfoTokenServices(userInfoUri, clientId);
      return tokenService;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: That didn't even initialize. `Application startup failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri' in value "${security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri}"`

Comment: just check, how to use '@value' annotation!! then it will work